# VBA automatic type conversion

Tags: vba

I come from a C++ world and I am going through first steps in VBA classes.

Say I have a class for a smart Date, i.e. QDate

```
 *** Class Module ***
 Option explicit
 Private xDate_ As Date

 Property Let xDate(xVal As Date)
      xDate_ = xVal
 End Property

 Property Get xDate() As Date
     xDate = xDate_
 End Property

 ' ... some nice methods follow here...


 *** non-Class Module *** 
 Public Function makeQDate() As QDate
    Set makeQDate = New QDate
 End Function
```

Sample usage might be

```
 Dim xQDate as QDate :  xQDate = makeQDate()
 xQDate.xDate = DateSerial(2000,1,1)
```

The last line is not as nice as one could get in C++. If we could create implicit conversion that would allow to write

```
 xQDate = DateSerial(2000,1,1)
```

it would be awesome. Is something like that achievable in VBA?
Many thanks.

Comment: one tip- you could make one method/property default one, it's the only idea I could suggest. In that situation last and last-but-one line of your code would be the same...

Comment: Setting a default member in VBA isn't possible in the editor, you have to do some magic as described here - http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DefaultMember.aspx

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware, VBA doesn't support custom implicit conversions, only built-in ones. But, you're right—it would be awesome.